# Extracting the relative influence from a gbm.fit object

Tags: r, gbm

I am trying to extract the relative influence of each variable from a gbm.fit object but it is coming up with the error below:

```
       > summary(boost_cox, plotit = FALSE)
       Error in data.frame(var = object$var.names[i], rel.inf = rel.inf[i]) : 
       row names contain missing values
```

The `boost_cox` object itself is fitted as follows:

```
    boost_cox = gbm.fit(x = x,
                        y = y,
                        distribution="coxph",
                        verbose = FALSE,
                        keep.data = TRUE)
```

I have to use the `gbm.fit` function rather than the standard `gbm` function due to the large number of predictors (26k+)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solve this issue now myself.

The `relative.influence()` function can be used and works for objects created using both `gbm()` and `gbm.fit()`. However, it does not provide the plots as in the `summary()` function.

I hope this helps anyone else looking in the future.